# I am getting a void value not ignored as it ought to be error why?

Tags: c++, error-handling, linked-list, void

The rotate function is void with 1 `int` argument. I don't know why I am getting this error. It's only a void function with 2 statements.

`head_ptr_` is a private linked list variable.

`getNodeAt` returns the node at a the given position "`position`". Since it is returning a node we can access its members assignment works right to left. It completes everything on the right side of the operand before assigning. If I am wrong feel free to fix my knowledge.

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::rotate(int k)
{
    head_ptr_ = getNodeAt(k)->setNext(head_ptr_);//error here
    head_ptr_ = getNodeAt(k-1)->setNext(nullptr);
}//end of rotate

template<class T>
Node<T>* LinkedList<T>::getNodeAt(int position) const
{
    // Count from the beginning of the chain
    Node<T>* cur_ptr = head_ptr_;
    for (int skip = 0; skip < position; skip++)
        cur_ptr = cur_ptr->getNext();

    return cur_ptr;
}  // end getNodeAt

int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> bag1;

    for(int i = 14;i >= 10;i--)
    {
        bag1.insert(bag1.getLength(),i);
    }
    bag1.print();
    cout << endl;
    //bag1.invert();
    bag1.rotate(3);
    bag1.print();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Comment: `getting this error` - what error?

Comment: Does `setNext` return anything?

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't have a separate `.cpp` file for `template` classes. You must have the declaration and definition in one file.

Comment: @KamilCuk Error message is at bottom of code block.

Comment: Your setNext() function returns void and you are trying to assign the return value of setNext() to a variable.

Comment: @Advancedip: Please provide a [repro], at the very least the declaration of `setNext`. Most likely it is returning `void`, which cannot be assigned to `head_ptr_`.

Answer (score 1):

**Analysis of the error:**

> *error:* void value not ignored as it ought to be.

This is a GCC error message that means the return-value of a function is 'void', but that you are trying to assign it to a non-void variable.

**Your particular case :**
Your *setNext()* most likely returns void and you're trying to store it's return result to a variable, thats why your getting the error you mentioned in these two lines of code that you posted in your rotate function :

```
head_ptr_ = getNodeAt(k)->setNext(head_ptr_);//error here
head_ptr_ = getNodeAt(k-1)->setNext(nullptr);
```

You can solve the problem in 2 ways :
**1st Solution :**
Change your code to be like this and apply the necessary changes to maintain the same logic:

```
getNodeAt(k)->setNext(head_ptr_);
getNodeAt(k-1)->setNext(nullptr);
```

**2nd Solution :**
Change your *setNext()* function to return a valid pointer (don't also forget to change the method declaration to return *Node* pointer):

```
template<class T>
Node<T>* LinkedList<T>::setNext(Node<T>* next)
{
    // same logic here as before
    return ptr; // where ptr is a valid pointer that you want to return
}
```